# Android: when implementing a music player in my app, can i make sure there is no other media playing playing music right now?

Tags: android, media-player

I want my app to play music while it is running, but I don't want the music to overlap with the music currently being played from a different application (android music app or other external music app such as pandora, grooveshark or winamp).
My question is: is there a way to make sure that nothing else is playing right now regardless of the source?

Thanks!

Comment: I think(but am not positive) that the system only has one MediaPlayer object. If another app has it and hasn't called .release() on it yet then you aren't going to be able to get it for yourself.

Comment: well, from my checks, there are apps that play music overlapping each other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of android 2.2 you can use `AudioManager.requestAudioFocus()`, other audio players should listen for this focus change request and can stop/pause/lower volume of their audio according to what type of audio your focus requests. However not all audio playing apps have bothered to implement this yet.

To be nice you should also listen for audio focus change requests from other apps and pause your apps audio accordingly.

On earlier versions of android calling `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` will usually stop any other music from playing

Comment: So the answer is that there is no guarantee that I'll be able to stop music from playing elsewhere, correct?

Comment: yes. Myself, I have just implemented the audio focus method as its quite easy to do and simply hope that in time most popular music players will implement it too